# expected mutable reference `&mut egui::ui::Ui` found mutable reference `&mut Ui` should not be happening

Tags: image, rust, egui, eframe

Here is the repo im using as a reference for adding a image:
https://github.com/emilk/egui/blob/master/examples/retained_image/src/main.rs

Im getting this error when trying to draw a image to the screen on this line of code:

```
date_backdrop.show(ui);
```

"mismatched types
expected mutable reference `&mut egui::ui::Ui`
found mutable reference `&mut Ui`
perhaps two different versions of crate `egui` are being used?"

dont understand how to fix this issue. still new to rust

here is my code:

```
use eframe::egui;
use egui_extras::RetainedImage;
struct InitView;


impl eframe::epi::App for InitView {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        "CheckIt"
    }
    
    fn update(&mut self,ctx: &eframe::egui::CtxRef,frame: &mut eframe::epi::Frame<'_>) {
        
        let date_backdrop = RetainedImage::from_image_bytes(
            "date_backdrop.png",
            include_bytes!("date_backdrop.png"),
        )
        .unwrap();
        
        //background color
        let frame = egui::containers::Frame {
            fill: egui::Color32::from_rgb(241, 233, 218),
            ..Default::default()
        };
        
        //main window
        egui::CentralPanel::default().frame(frame).show(ctx, |ui| {
            ui.heading("This is an image:");
            date_backdrop.show(ui);
           
        });
    }
}

fn main(){
    let app: InitView = InitView;
    let win_options = eframe::NativeOptions{
        initial_window_size: Some(egui::Vec2::new(386.0, 636.0)),
        always_on_top: true,
        resizable: false,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    eframe::run_native(Box::new(app), win_options);
}
```

Here is my Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "checkit"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
eframe = "0.14.0"
image = { version = "0.24", default-features = false, features = ["png"] }
egui_extras = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["image"] }
```

Comment: What's in your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: updated the post so you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error tells, you have two incompatible version of `egui` in the dependency tree: `eframe 0.14` [pulls in `egui 0.14`](https://crates.io/crates/eframe/0.14.0/dependencies), while `egui_extras 0.20` [pulls in `egui 0.20`](https://crates.io/crates/egui_extras/0.20.0/dependencies). When major version is 0, different minor versions [are treated as incompatible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-cratesio), therefore the types from them are not interchangable.

As far as I can see, both `eframe` and `egui_extras` depend on the same minor version of `egui` as their own version, so you have to synchronize these two dependencies to use the same minor version. The easiest way is probably to bump `eframe` to `0.20`.